# VBA For each pivot within workbook update datasource range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop though each worksheet in my workbook and reset all pivot data ranges to range("D1_Data") before refreshing.
Currently getting a Runtime error '1004' with the below code and somewhat stuck, any ideas?

Note that "TemplateWB" has been pre-set else where in my code as a workbook which the code is currently operating in.

```
'Set Dim
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim WS As Worksheet

'Set D1_Data
    TemplateWB.Sheets("Data_1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(NewLastRow, NewLastColumn + 4)).Name = "D1_Data"

    For Each WS In TemplateWB.Worksheets

        For Each PT In WS.PivotTables

        With PT.PivotCache
            .SourceData = Range("D1_Data").Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
            .Refresh
        End With

        Next PT

    Next WS
```

Comment: all of your Pivot-Tables have the same Data source ? in `TemplateWB.Sheets("Data_1")` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes, I have four pivot tables over two tabs which are pointing to the same source.

Comment: Strange. It should work. It work with only one PivotTable, or with multiple PivotTable with DIFFERENT data source, or if the datasource don't change. But as soon all pivot have same source data, it's crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (I tested it on multiple Pivot Tables across different worksheets and it worked).

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoRefreshPivot()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PTCache As PivotCache

Dim NewLastRow As Long, NewLastColumn As Long
Dim TemplateWB As Workbook    

' values for my internal testing
'Set TemplateWB = ThisWorkbook
'NewLastRow = 11
'NewLastColumn = 4

'Set D1_Data
TemplateWB.Sheets("Data_1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(NewLastRow, NewLastColumn + 4)).Name = "D1_Data"

For Each WS In TemplateWB.Worksheets

    For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
        ' set Pivot Cache to updated data source range (per each Pivot Table)
        Set PTCache = TemplateWB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=Range("D1_Data").Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True), _
            Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

        With PT
            .ChangePivotCache PTCache
           ' .Refresh
        End With
        ' need to clear the cache every time after being used for a Pivot table
        Set PTCache = Nothing
    Next PT
Next WS

End Sub
```